# Why do I need a C++ compiler to compile Rust?

Tags: rust

This could be a very dumb question, but I'm wondering why the Rust compiler (written in Rust itself) require a C++ compiler.

I mean, a precompiled Rust compiler from the distribution should be enough, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, but there's no point in compiling the rust compiler with a downloaded rust compiler

Comment: @joris_van_winden: Actually that is the only way to build the Rust compiler, as it is written in Rust. The thing is that you can build the latest version of the Rust compiler using an older one. It is not different with the GCC, it is written in C so you need a C compiler (C++ in newer versions) to build it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is actually a reasonable question. The answer is that currently, the rust source includes a slightly patched version of [LLVM](https://github.com/rust-lang/llvm), LLVM is written in C++, and that is not distributed in binary form. So you need a C++ compiler to build that.

Comment: So I could not use llvm-cbe (https://github.com/draperlaboratory/llvm-cbe) to compile rust to c an then port it to an os without a c++ compiler, right?

Comment: @GiacomoTesio: Well, you might succeed with that. But I think you have better chances cross-compiling Rust from a supported platform.

Comment: @GiacomoTesio The platform not having a C++ compiler is a bad reason, since both rustc and LLVM have good cross compilation support. The platform not having an LLVM backend would be a better reason, but I am very doubtful whether this would work well.

Comment: @delnan can you elaborate a bit about your doubts? Any link to previous experiences? The target platform I'm considering doesn't have an LLVM backend.

Comment: @GiacomoTesio For starters, the C backend would have to perfectly map the semantics of the LLVM IR, with all important corner cases, to standard C, and your target C compiler must honor the standard flawlessly. That's already two big assumptions. Furthermore, LLVM IR is not at all portable: The sizes of data types, the ABI, and various other platform assumptions are baked into the IR generated by the frontend.